# push contents of a whole array into one index of a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am pulling different information from different sources. This information is dynamic. I want to consolidate it all into a multidimensional array. I was doing fine until I ran into problems trying to push the dynamic information into the multidimensional array.

At this point I don't even know what to google to find the solution I need. Below is a simplified example of the code. The highlights being:

1. Only the occupants of the tents change
2. There is no set number of occupants per tent. (There will always
   be at least two occupants, but there is no upper limit.)

Example code:

```
var InformationByTent = [];
var numberOfOccupants;
var Tent01Occupants = ["John", "Sam", "Harry"];
var Tent02Occupants = ["Dawn", "Amy", "Jane"];
var Tent03Occupants = ["Nate", "Peter"];
var arrayOfArrays = [Tent01Occupants, Tent02Occupants, Tent03Occupants];
var totalNumberTents = arrayOfArrays.length;
var CampDuties = ["Build Fire", "Cook Dinner", "Sentry", "Hike Preparation"]
var FridayDuty;
var SaturdayDuty;
var SundayDuty;

for (i = 0; i < totalNumberTents; i++) {
//  Assume there are lines of code here that randomizes the duties and assigns three
//  of those to the FridayDuty, SaturdayDuty, SundayDuty variables. Results:
//  FridayDuty = "Build Fire";
//  SaturdayDuty = "Hike Preparation";
//  SundayDuty = "Cook Dinner";
numberOfOccupants = Tent01Occupants.length;
    InformationByTent.push({
        tentNum: i + 1,
        Friday: FridayDuty,
        Saturday: SaturdayDuty,
        Sunday: SundayDuty,
            }); 
    }
```

Wanted End Results:

```
InformationByTent = [
{tentNum:1,Occupant01:"John",Occupant02:"Sam",Occupant03:"Harry",Friday:"Build Fire",Saturday:"Hike Preparation",Sunday:"Cook Dinner"},
{tentNum:2,Occupant01:"Dawn",Occupant02:"Amy",Occupant03:"Jane",Friday:"Hike Preparation",Saturday:"Sentry",Sunday:"Build Fire"},
{tentNum:3,Occupant01:"Nate",Occupant02:"Peter",Friday:"Cook Dinner",Saturday:"Cook Dinner",Sunday:"Sentry"},]
```

What I don't know how to define the identifiers or write the syntax/method to push this:

```
Occupant01:tent01Occupants[0],
Occupant02:tent01Occupants[1],
Occupant03:tent01Occupants[2]
```

..when I don't know how many occupants there is going to be in each array. Any pointers would be helpful!

Comment: It is quite strange to have `Occupant01`, `Occupant02`, etc. keys instead of a `Occupants` key with an array of `Occupant`.

Comment: You make a very good point, Holt.. I swear I had a reason why I need it like that, but I confess I can't remember it now. I do want to say thanks for cluing me into the 'key' jargon though. I knew that had to be called a specific name, but google didn't understand my attempts to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about doing:

```
var info;
for (i = 0; i < totalNumberTents; i++) {
//  Assume there are lines of code here that randomizes the duties and assigns three
//  of those to the FridayDuty, SaturdayDuty, SundayDuty variables. Results:
//  FridayDuty = "Build Fire";
//  SaturdayDuty = "Hike Preparation";
//  SundayDuty = "Cook Dinner";
numberOfOccupants = Tent01Occupants.length;
    info = {
        tentNum: i + 1,
        Friday: FridayDuty,
        Saturday: SaturdayDuty,
        Sunday: SundayDuty,
     };
     for (var x = 0; x < Tent01Occupants.length; x++) {
       info["Occupant" + (x + 1)] = Tent010Occupants[x];
     }
     // And repeat the same for other variables
    InformationByTent.push(info); 
    }
```

Comment: It works! You had the missing piece of knowledge I lacked. What exactly is `info`? As in, what kind of variable? Or what is the method being implemented there? That way I can research it so when I need to do this in the future, I can say: Oh, I need to do [whatever `info` is]!

Comment: Info is defined above (name could be anything). It is just a "placeholder" for your object while it is being created. It contains everything except the names at the beginning but then you start populating it with the loops. Then, you just add that object to the array and it will contain everything what you need :)